# Every Archimedean Ordered Field is field isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: ordered-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an archimedean ordered field. Then $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{F}$, then define $S_x:=\{\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}: \frac{m_{\mathbb{F}}}{n_{\mathbb{F}}}<x\}$.$\mathbb{F}$ being archimedean makes $S_x$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $\phi:\mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(x)=\operatorname{lub}S_x$

**Claim 1:** $\phi$ is injective.

Let $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{F}$ with $x_1<x_2$ one can obtain an element of the form $\frac{m_{\mathbb{F}}}{n_\mathbb{F}}$ such that $x_1<\frac{m_{\mathbb{F}}}{n_\mathbb{F}}<x_2$.

Now how can I show that $\phi(x_1) \le \frac{m}{n}$?

**Claim 2:** $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ i.e $\operatorname{lub}S_{x+y}=\operatorname{lub}S_x+\operatorname{lub}S_y$

From the construction of $S_{a}$ it follows $S_x+S_y \subseteq S_{x+y}$ $\implies$
$\phi(x)+\phi(y) \le \phi(x+y)$

How do I show the reverse inequality?

**Claim 3:** $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ i.e $\operatorname{lub}S_{xy}=\operatorname{lub}
S_{x}\operatorname{lub}S_y$

How do I do this?

Comment: 1. $S_{x_1} \subseteq S_{m/n}$, right? Hence $\phi(x_1) \leq \phi(m/n) = m/n$.

Comment: @PaulK: Can you tell me anything about the other claims?

Comment: Rougly:
Let $m/n < x+y$ be some rational, look at the distance $h = x + y - m / n$. Now take some rational in $x - h/2$ and $y - h/2$. Their some is rational and larger then $m / n$. A similar idea should work for 3.

Comment: @PaulK: I tried doing the 3rd claim in a similar way. But am completely stuck since yesterday. Can you please provide me an answer

Comment: Maybe look at the proof that multiplication $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous (or that the product of convergent sequences is convergent).

Answer (score 0):

I am writing @Paul K comment as an answer:

**Claim 2:** $\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+\Phi(y)$ $\implies$
$\operatorname{lub}S_{x+y}=\operatorname{lub}S_x+\operatorname{lub}S_y$

By construction:
$S_x+S_y \subseteq S_{x+y} 
\Rightarrow \operatorname{lub}(S_x+S_y) \le \operatorname{lub}S_{x+y}$
$\Rightarrow \operatorname{lub}S_x+\operatorname{lub}S_y \le \operatorname{lub}S_{x+y}$
$\Rightarrow \phi(x)+\phi(y) \le \phi(x+y)$.

Let $q \in S_{x+y}$ 
$\Rightarrow$ $q_{\mathbb{F}}<x+y$.
Define $h=\left(x+y-q_{\mathbb{F}}\right)$.

Choose $p \in S_x$ and $t \in S_y$ with $x-h/2<p_\mathbb{F}<x$ and $y-h/2<t_{\mathbb{F}}<y$. 
$\Rightarrow$ $x+y-h<p_{\mathbb{F}}+t_{\mathbb{F}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $q_{\mathbb{F}}<p_{\mathbb{F}}+t_{\mathbb{F}}=(p+t)_{\mathbb{F}}$. 
So $q<p+t\le \Phi(x)+\Phi(y)$.
$\Phi(x)+\Phi(y)$ is an upperbound of $S_{x+y}$
$\Rightarrow \Phi(x+y)\le \Phi(x)+\Phi(y)$
Hence $\Phi(x+y)=\Phi(x)+\Phi(y)$.